# Javers commit author name

Tags: spring-boot, javers

following question:
I'm using Javers in my Spring Boot project, and want to extract the commit author name.

The value of `snapshots.get(0).getCommitMetadata().getAuthor()` gives only something like `TokenPayload@254d2bf`.

The first idea was to set the AuthorProvider Bean

```
@Bean
public AuthorProvider authorProvider() {
  return new SpringSecurityAuthorProvider();
}
```

but it didn't help.
No extra configuration is used, only the default one.
Thank you in advance.

```
Javers Version: 5.8.9
Spring Boot Version: 1.5.8
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the rigth `AuthorProvider` bean, which plays along with you Spring Security setup. `SpringSecurityAuthorProvider` which is provided by Javers is just the default implementation.

```java
/**
 * Returns a current user name from Spring Security context
 */
public class SpringSecurityAuthorProvider implements AuthorProvider {
    @Override
    public String provide() {
        Authentication auth =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (auth == null) {
            return "unauthenticated";
        }

        return auth.getName();
    }
}
```