# How to change the the author field in commitMetadata in Javers

Tags: java, spring-boot, javers

If anybody could help will be appreciated spring boot application i am using javers to store audit of entity classes.
Currently:

```
[
  {
    "changeType": "ValueChange",
    "globalId": {
      "valueObject": "com.genting.dc.adminportal.entity.ConfigFields",
      "ownerId": {
        "entity": "com.genting.dc.adminportal.entity.Config",
        "cdoId": "5e5ca82cc44900963f68096f"
      },
      "fragment": "source/register/registerStep1Fields/1"
    },
    "commitMetadata": {
      "author": "unauthenticated",
      "properties": [],
      "commitDate": "2020-03-24T15:47:40.844",
      "commitDateInstant": "2020-03-24T10:17:40.844Z",
      "id": 11.00
    },
    "property": "isMandatory",
    "left": true,
    "right": false
]
```

So now i want the author field to use value as set by the developer and not as '/unauthenticated'.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following question. It is is quite similar to the one you asked [Javers commit author name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577908/javers-commit-author-name)